# Simple batch script random number generator

Tags: batch-file, random

I am new to using the %random% command in batch scripts and I am trying to create a batch script to randomly create a number between 0 and 3.  I wrote the following but with every instance (everytime I double-click the BAT file) I get the same number '1'.  This defeats the purpose.  Which is based on this number copy over a selected video file so it is random.

```
echo off 
set numb=" "
set /a numb=%random% / 10000 
echo %numb% :only used for testing 
pause :only used for testing

if %numb% LEQ 1 goto trailer
if %numb% EQU 2 goto dragon
if %numb% EQU 3 goto live

:dragon
echo Dragon
copy /Y "F:\Skyrim SSE\mod backup - files\Dragon flyby - BGS_Logo.bik" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\Data\Video\BGS_Logo.bik"
exit

:trailer
echo Trailer
copy /Y "F:\Skyrim SSE\mod backup - files\Official Trailer-BGS_Logo.bik" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\Data\Video\BGS_Logo.bik" 
exit

:live
Echo Live
copy /Y "F:\Skyrim SSE\mod backup - files\Dragonborne-live-BGS_Logo.bik" "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\Data\Video\BGS_Logo.bik" 
exit
```

---

I want to keep this as simple as possible as this really doesn't need to be complicated.  Please help

Comment: For formatting - simply select your code text and press `{}`. You can edit your question by pressing `edit` under the tags currently `batch-file random`

Comment: I'll invite you to edit your question since the code from your "answer" (which I used to replace your original - and you should delete your "answer" as it will be deleted as "not an answer") um - makes no real sense. Note that a label must be alone on a line - you cannot add an instruction as you can in assembler...

Comment: You figured out how-to-post or you figured out the solution to your problem?

Comment: %random% is not that random https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100617-00/?p=13673

Comment: set /a numb=%random%%% 3.  This creates a number 0 thru 2 (3 numbers).  Also the issue I was seeing was because I was dividing by 10000 (what I found online when I didn't fully understand the %random% function) it was actually creating a random number just in the 10k to 20k range (19999) so when it was divided the resulting number was always '1'.  Also in the future if I copy and paste code here I will do it one line a time (maybe that will make a difference).

Comment: You'll see a rendering of your post under the edit window - should be of some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one way to do it:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "_s=F:\Skyrim SSE\mod backup - files"
Set "_d=D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\Data\Video\BGS_Logo.bik"

Set/A "_r=%RANDOM%%%3"
>Nul Choice /C 012 /N /T 0 /D %_r%
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo Dragon
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Trailer
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo Live
GoTo :EOF

:Dragon
Echo(Dragon
Copy /Y "%_s%\Dragon flyby - BGS_Logo.bik" "%_d%"
GoTo EndIt

:Trailer
Echo(Trailer
Copy /Y "%_s%\Official Trailer-BGS_Logo.bik" "%_d%"
GoTo EndIt

:Live
Echo(Live
Copy /Y "%_s%\Dragonborne-live-BGS_Logo.bik" "%_d%"

:EndIt
GoTo :EOF
```

I used `CHOICE` for no real reason, *I just preferred it to a series of `IF`'s with comparison operators ,`EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ`*.